# ffmpeg - How to use all the CPU of the server?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using this command to run ffmpeg -

```
ffmpeg -i -  -isync  -threads 16  -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -ar 22050 -r 25 -s 640x360 -strict experimental  -b:a 32k -b:v 100k -f flv "rtmp://"  -threads 16  -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -ar 22050 -r 25 -s 640x360 -strict experimental  -b:a 32k -b:v 400k -f flv "rtmp://"
```

I am running ffmpeg processes on my server. Currently ffmpeg don't use all my CPU, I want to use all my CPU usage.

My server has 24 CPU, 16 GB RAM, and 1 TB HDD. Please tell me the command to use all my CPU usage, and to make my ffmpeg smooth.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0% idle and 0% wait. That is using 100% of your CPU. Your computer is just not powerful enough to process 20 videos simultaneously. You can try adding the 'ultrafast' option to use less CPU per encode (at the price of lower quality)

Comment: No, to resize you must decode then scale then encode. You can not scale an encoded image